# JQuery POST showing as empty array in PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

In a JS file I am performing this function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {

        //get the button's ID (which is equal to its row's report_id)
        var emergency = this.id;
        var button = this.attributes['name'].value;
        var dataString = 'reportid=' + emergency;

        alert(dataString);
        if (button == "clockin") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/employeetimeclock.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    window.location = "/employeetimeclock.php";
                }
            });
        } else if (button == "closereport") {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to close this report?\nThis action CANNOT be undone!");
            if (r == true) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/closeemergencyreport.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function() {
                        alert("Report Successfully Closed!");
                        window.location = "/closeemergencyreport.php";
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("An error has occured, the report was not closed");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Report was not closed.");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For the else if (to closeemergencyreport.php) the code in that php script is as follows:

```
<?php

require_once("models/config.php");
require_once("models/header.php");
require_once("models/dbconnect.php");


$reportid = $_POST['reportid'];


var_dump($_POST);


$sql = "UPDATE emergency_report SET report_closed = '1' WHERE report_id IN ( $reportid )";
//execute and test if succesful
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($result){
} else{
}
?>
```

I've done this same exact thing on 3 other pages and it works flawlessly however this is giving me trouble where on that php script the VAR_DUMP is saying it's returning an empty array. I've been reading and rereading the code for about an hour and a half now so I think i'm burnt out and need to have an outside view. Ive been all over the site and no one has had a solution that worked for me.

I know it's posting because fire bug is showing this on the form's page that the javascript is run on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g33By.png (sorry cant post images yet)

Comment: have you tried commenting out all your require_once statements to make sure one of those scripts isn't messing up your $_POST array?

Comment: are you sure that the URL started with `/` in other files? I think you need to remove this slash `url: "/closeemergencyreport.php",` then change it to `url: "closeemergencyreport.php",`

Comment: @alexp the require_once statements are present in all of the other files just as they are put in this one.

Comment: @akam I just tried without the "/" and it still didnt work. The "/" is present in all the other files as well

Comment: try this. var dataString = {"reportid": emergency}
I think that by concatenating to make dataString you are causing a problem. I am not entirely sure about this but it would seem that you are sending a string to the server and not an object. this is a bit baffling and that's the best i could come up with so far.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe it is suppose to be a string, not an object. as i said above, i simply copied and altered the same code ive been using and that has been working up until this page/script

Comment: was a shot in the dark. im scratching my head right now