# PHP AJAX POST data passing and then removes itself?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So in light of my recent question i did some more heavy digging and ran into this oddity... my problem right now is that I cant pass my _POST to a PHP variable because it keeps coming up as an empty array. However, looking deeper into firebug i noticed this:

[image]

What this means is that my POST is getting passed properly but at some point during rendering(?) its deleting itself or some such non-sense. Is anyone able to explain this or tell me how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you serialize the form before you pass it?

Comment: @nathanhayfield i've not needed to before. I have 3 other pages that are coded the exact same way and they all work. this page is just a mystery and giving me a hard time. If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509084/jquery-post-showing-as-empty-array-in-php-script you can see waht i mean

Comment: on the linked question, I am confused why you have a completely empty if statement at the bottom... `if ($result) { } else { }`

Comment: @JeffShaver That was just leftover code that got copied over when i created the script. This script is an altered clone of about 3 other scripts i run for other pages that all work flawlessly. This one for some mysterious reason doesnt seem to want to play nice with $_POST data